# Why does the 'this' keyword inside event handlers of document.body refer to the global window object?

Tags: javascript, this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            height: 1000px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.onscroll = function() {
            alert(this);// displays [object Window], instead of [object HTMLBodyElement]
        };

        document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
            alert(this);// displays [object HTMLButtonElement]
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the `this` keyword in a button element event handler and in another handler of the body element, but the second `this` keyword referred to the global window object. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `body` element exposes as event handler content attributes a number of the event handlers of the Window object.

Such events are, currently: `blur`, `error`, `focus`, `load`, `resize` and `scroll`.

This list is called *"Window-reflecting body element event handler set"*.

(See, for example: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/webappapis.html)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('btn').onclick` returns `object HTMLButtonElement` because `this` refers to the object that is being invoked. In this case, it is it the button element.

`this` is not related to scope but to calling context. You are calling `this` on the body element when scrolling. However the body is not scrolling, so this is going to reference the default object which returns the window. (Window in a browser).